# How to Upload an Image to Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I have spent over three days on this. It appears that something saved to the db, but when I try to access it in the template, I can only get the object of the db. I can not access it. I believe it was not saved successfully because I don't see a media folder where it would be saved. This is what I have so far.

```py
# settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), )
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

```py
# forms.py
from .models import Pic
from django import forms
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Pic
        fields= ["picture"]
```

```py
# models.py
class Pic(models.Model):
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/', default = 'media/None/no-img.jpg', null=True, blank= True)
```

```py
# views.py
def upload(request):
    form = ImageForm
    context = {}
    userBio = Bio.objects.get(userData = User.objects.get(id = request.session['client']['id']))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # .is_valid checks the models parameters via forms method
        form = ImageForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print("succesful uploaded image")
            return redirect("/dashboard")
        else:
            print("Not a valid input from form....")
            messages.error(request,"Not a valid input")
    return redirect("/dashboard")
```

```html
<!-- dashboard.html -->
<form rule="form" class="border border--secondary" method="POST" action="/manageFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token%}
    <input type="file" name = "update">
    <input type = "submit">
</form>
{% if pictures %}
    {% for pic in pictures%}
        <img src="{{pic}}" alt="{{pic}}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endif%}
```

In the template, it appears as Pic object(1).
In the terminal, it appears as

> Query set Pic: Pic object (1)

Here's what I render to the template.

```py
def dash(request):
    try:
        _id = request.session['client']['id']
    except:
        return redirect("/loginPg")

    userBio = Bio.objects.get(userData = User.objects.get(id = request.session['client']['id']))
    print("its right here")
    theUploads = Pic.objects.all()
    print("This image object -", theUploads)

    content = {
        "title" : userBio.title,
        "qA" : userBio.quoteA,
        "qB" : userBio.quoteB,
        "desc" : userBio.desc,
        "authorA" : userBio.authorA,
        "authorB" : userBio.authorB,
        "pictures" : theUploads
    }

    return render(request, "GoEnigma/dashboard.html", content)
```

```py
# urls.py
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
# urls []
if settings.DEBUG:
     urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: It appears only the default from the model parameter is being saved. This is what I see in the template. /media/media/None/no-img.jpg

Comment: If `upload` is a method of the Pic model, then the site would not start up, because of circular imports. I think upload is in views.py? And you're missing a return statement in that too.

Comment: The upload request method is in the views.py. I am returning a redirect if the form is valid. What's interesting is that the default from the model is the only thing being saved. So far I have two urls that are the same. Which look like this. /media/media/None/no-img.jpg

Comment: `<input type="file" name = "update">` is just arbitrary, put the same field name: `picture` instead of `update`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was hard to spot, because you render the form field yourself:

```py
class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= Pic
        fields= ["picture"]
```

```html
    <input type="file" name = "update">
```

So the name of the file field is update, not picture. Change that to picture and it should work, though it's much better to use django to render the form, so you don't mistakes like this and changes to the form get propagated to the html.

Comment: I was using form to use .is_valid. But I may have to reconsider it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

put parentheses after  ImageForm and add request.POST in ImageForm if it is Post request.

```
def upload:
  form = ImageForm()
  if request.method == 'POST':
    # .is_valid checks the models parameters via forms method
    form = ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        print("succesful uploaded image")
        return redirect("/dashboard")
    else:
        print("Not a valid input from form....")
        messages.error(request,"Not a valid input")
return redirect("/dashboard")
```

Also check maybe you haven't added url path for serving media files
so add these following lines in `urls.py` file of `main project`.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
  # ..... all regular paths
] 
if setting.DEBUG: # if true
  urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Check official documents [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Comment: I have, unfortunately its the same issue.

Comment: @Anthony I've updated answer check if you have added urlspattens for MEDIA FILES.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that. I do already have that for the MEDIA FILES.

Comment: I do have that already, sorry I forgot to add that to my question. I edited the question just now.

Answer (score 0):

If the picture is being saved in the database than the error is with rendering the template. To render the images in template you need to get the {{model_class.model_fields.url}} so in your case the class is pic, the field is picture.
try this in your template `<img src="{{pic.picture.url}}">`

Comment: The url is displaying. The only urls displaying are from the default in the model. I have two urls in the model that look like this /media/media/None/no-img.jpg

Comment: Try rendering the default pic in template itself. For example: if picture than show the pic else get the default image

Comment: @Anthony please update your template code then, @ngawang13 is right, if there is Pic instances (display `Pic object (1)`), the template is wrong and should display the url. If the url is always displaying your default, then there is also a problem on saving. Be sure to put your actual code is the question.

Comment: Is the image being saved in the database and try removing the if statement and load the template